# How to center a Label with an ImageView next to it in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have a `UIImageView` next to a `UILabel` with dynamic content. Both within a `StackView`.

[image]

Currently I'm using the `Fill` Alignment and Distribution. Changing it to one of the other options, changes the size of the `ImageView` (fixed Constraints to 30x30).The `StackView` has left and right leading Constraints of `0`.

This is my current:

[image]

The is what I want:

[image]

How do I need to set up the StackView to archive my goals? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try using a vertical stack view with an embedded horizontal stack view.

[image]

The first stack view has a vertical axis. Its alignment is centre and the distribution is fill (the default). This stack view has the following constraints: Trailing to superview, leading to superview and top space to top layout guide.

The second stack view contains the image view and label. Its axis is horizontal. The fill alignment and distributions are set to their default values. The spacing is set to 10 (can be changed to suit your needs). This stack view has no constraints.

The image view has a height and width constraints of 30 respectively.

The label has no constraints.

Both the image view and label have default content hugging and compression values.

[image]

If the label has longer text then then it will appear like this:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manipulating content hugging and content compression resistance priority ? I believe these property will let you manage the length distance between both the image view and textView, and the stack view won't let you dynamically expend the textView as you enter more and more data so I think manipulating the hugging and resistance properties can give you a solution close to the required.

Comment: where do i set those properties up?

Comment: Check out the attribute inspector. I recommend you read more about these property before manipulating them as they can get complex.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating a container view for the image view and the text label and then centering the container view in the original parent view.

Comment: i would not know how to handle different text label lengths then

Comment: also i dont really see the difference between that approach and using stackview

Comment: This should work for a label with dynamic content. Add constraints on the container view so that its width is the sum of that of the image view and the label. When you want to center views instead of stacking views, a stack view might not be the best choice.

Comment: okay i see. so the container view is centered in the view. containing imageview and label. its width is the sum of the 2 elements... hm could work. i'll try

Answer (score 0):

**iOS Center several views**

```
Vertical StackView(Axis - Vertical):
Alignment: Center
Distribution: Fill
constraint to superview

    Horizontal StackView(Axis - Horizontal): 
    Alignment: Top
    Distribution: Fill

        UIImageView:
        WidthxHeight constraints

        UILabel:
        Lines:0
```

[image]
[image]
[image]